# Set default output value if frequency of all input elements is the same

Tags: php, arrays, variables, count, default

Good day all, I hardly ever need to ask here because searching always yields the answers I am looking but this time I just don't know what to search for.

The following code works as expected and shows the desired result.

Note: There can always be only 3 results, namely "Average", "Above average" or "Below average"; example:

```
$test1 = 'Average';
$test2 = 'Above average';
$test3 = 'Average';

$mystuff = array($test1, $test2, $test3);
$result = array_count_values($mystuff);
asort($result);
end($result);
$answer = key($result);
echo 'Averaging : ' . $answer;
```

Working Example:

Input: `$test1='Average'` , `$test2='Above average'` , `$test3='Average'`

Expected output: `Averaging : Average`
(This is correct because it is the most frequent occurrence in the array.)

The problem is, when all three `$test` variables are different :

```
   $test1 = 'Above average';
   $test2 = 'Below average';
   $test3 = 'Average';
```

Now, `$answer = Above average` (ie. the first occurrence in the array).

However, I would like to set a default value when there is no "frequent occurrence".

What I would like to have is this:

If all three variables are different, then `$answer` must ALWAYS show 'Average', regardless of `$test1` or `$test2` or `$test3` values.

I don't expect you to give the code I need, just point my in the right direction as to what to search for.

Comment: Check out the `array_unique()` function. If the number of unique values is the same as the total number of values, then you know all three test variables are different.

Comment: Thank you @rickdenhaan. I will look into the array_unique function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method:

```
$result = array_count_values($mystuff);
if(sizeof($result)==1){                         // only one unique value
    $answer = key($result);                     // get lone element's value
}elseif(sizeof(array_flip($result))==1){        // if all value counts are same
    $answer = 'Average';                        // set default value
}else{
    arsort($result);                            // sort DESC
    $answer = key($result);                     // get first element's value
}
echo "Averaging : $answer";
```

Inputs/Outputs:

```
$mystuff=['Average','Below Average','Below Average'];        // Averaging : Below Average
$mystuff=['Average','Above Average','Below Average'];        // Averaging : Average
$mystuff=['Above Average','Above Average','Above Average'];  // Averaging : Above Average
```

---

Just some notes, I have opted for `array_flip()` over `array_unique()` because it is a faster performer and it provides a result that is equally useful.

I could have written my method with just two conditions like:

```
$result = array_count_values($mystuff);
if(sizeof($result)>1 && sizeof(array_flip($result))==1){
    $answer = 'Average';                        // set default value
}else{
    arsort($result);                            // sort DESC
    $answer = key($result);                     // get first element's value
}
echo "Averaging : $answer";
```

However, that would mean that `arsort()` could be senselessly sorting a one-element array.  I mean, it's no big deal -- especially because arsort() is fast and your array is so small.  So, I guess what I am saying is, if code brevity is important to you, use this alternative method.

Comment: Thank you @mickmackusa. The IF ELSE statements makes sense to me and your answer obviously yielded the exact result I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: Seems I spoke to soon; When all 3 $test values are different, then it sets the default to 'average. This is correct.

Comment: It is also correct when  $mystuff=['Above Average','Above Average','Average'];  // Averaging : Above Average

Comment: But when all 3 $test values are the SAME, eg $mystuff=['Above Average','Above Average','Above Average'];  // Averaging : (Should be) Above Average, but with this code it defaults to 'Average'. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What I mean is that I want the Default 'Average', only when all 3 $test values are DIFFERENT from each other. I hope I am explaining myself correctly.

Comment: @jamie Sorry for that slip up.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @mick. Now it works perfect. And your //comments(in the code) helps alot with me still being in a learning process. Thank you.